# Collect complex objects in one lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream, grouping

I have a list of objects. At first, I need to sort it by type.
Than by faceValue. In the end, summarize all quantities:

```
      class Coin{
            String type;
            BigInteger faceValue;
            BigInteger quantity;
...
       }

            List<Coin> coins = new ArrayList<>();
            coins.add(new Coin("USD", 1, 150));
            coins.add(new Coin("USD", 1, 6));
            coins.add(new Coin("USD", 1, 60));
            coins.add(new Coin("USD", 2, 100));
            coins.add(new Coin("USD", 2, 100));
            coins.add(new Coin("CAD", 1, 111));
            coins.add(new Coin("CAD", 1, 222));
```

Result list must contains only 3 new coin objects:

```
Coin("USD", 1 , 216)
Coin("USD", 2 , 200)
Coin("CAD", 1 , 333)
```

How can this be written only in one lambda expression?

Comment: When you say 'one lambda expression', do you really mean one lambda expression, or do you mean one call chain which might include _multiple_ lambdas (and method references, etc.)?

Comment: Do you need to stick with this design (which isn't optimal at all IMHO), or can you change the class design if you want to?

Comment: Yes, it might include multiple lambdas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve that using `Collectors.toMap` as :

```
public List<Coin> groupedCoins(List<Coin> coins) {
    return new ArrayList<>(
            coins.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                            coin -> Arrays.asList(coin.getType(), coin.getFaceValue()), Function.identity(),
                            (coin1, coin2) -> {
                                BigInteger netQ = coin1.getQuantity().add(coin2.getQuantity());
                                return new Coin(coin1.getType(), coin1.getFaceValue(), netQ);
                            }))
                    .values());
}
```

or a further complex one liner grouping and sum as :

```
public List<Coin> groupedAndSummedCoins(List<Coin> coins) {
    return coins.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Coin::getType,
                    Collectors.groupingBy(Coin::getFaceValue,
                            Collectors.reducing(BigInteger.ZERO, Coin::getQuantity, BigInteger::add))))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().entrySet().stream()
                    .map(a -> new Coin(e.getKey(), a.getKey(), a.getValue())))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Why on Earth is the first thing, people think of when grouping by multiple values, using potentially ambiguous, inefficient strings? Instead of `coin -> String.format("%s-%s", coin.getType(), coin.getFaceValue())`, you can simply use `coin -> Arrays.asList(coin.getType(), coin.getFaceValue())`.

Comment: Tnx! This is what I need!

Comment: @Holger I would admit I have seen that being used by a lot of people and read a similar code suggestion from you elsewhere as well, but yet the namespacing using a single key just comes naturally. I understand that these could be ambiguous and would try to avoid this in future use cases. Thanks for the reminding. :)

Comment: Besides the possibility of being ambiguous, the concatenation requires the conversion of every object to a string, followed by the string concatenation operation, each of them being potentially expensive, then, the string comparison is not cheap either. In contrast, the `List` just keeps references to the original objects and implements sufficient `hashCode` and `equals` for a sequence of objects. The string approach might be tempting because it looks so simple and hides all the associated costs.